# IE9 HTML/CSS comptability Issue

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9

I have this particular html code involving a couple of HTML5 features. The layout of the page is exactly what I am expecting on every browser (not tested on Opera) but with the addition of the HTML5 doctype, the "curvy" shape around "buy it" is no longer present, and the orange color that both "buttons" (do it and say it) are supposed to have disappears. Could anyone provide some pointers on how to get the page to look normal on all major CURRENT browsers. I have a fairly technical audience coming to my site, so non HTML 5 compliant browsers will not be an issue.

Original without doctype (You will have to copy/paste into chrome or firefox to see what I mean, sorry!):

http://jsfiddle.net/bRCw3/

With doctype:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZXXYy/

Thank you for any help you give me.

Comment: You can't paste complete HTML documents into jsfiddle. It provides its own document around the snippets that you put in the CSS, HTML and Javascript boxes. If you examine the actual source in the result frame, you will see that both have the same doctype, and the HTML document that you pasted is inside the body of the document, thus making an invalid document.

Comment: Ah thank you for the advice. I will know this next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've specified the orange background colour (FF9900) in two places without a preceding `#`. Quirks mode is forgiving on this but standards mode is stricter and will ignore it.

Just change `background-color:FF9900` to `background-color:#FF9900` in both places and you're good.